# Get data from three tables with JOIN

Tags: sql, t-sql

This is the scenario. There are three tables, TableA, TableB and Table C

TableA

| Id | Name | ProductId |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | product1 | prod1 |
| 2 | product2 | prod2 |

TableB

| Id | Name | ProductId | Code |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | RandomName | prod2 | testcode |

TableC

| Id | OfferName | ProductId | Code |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | HappyOffer | prod1 | testcode |

Expected Result

| TableA.ProductId | TableA.Name | TableB.Name | TableC.OfferName |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| prod2 | product2 | RandomName | null |
| prod1 | product1 | null | HappyOffer |

Table A's ProductId is foreign key to ProductId of TableB and Table C.

What would be a query to get this expected result by using where clause based on Code 'testcode'

Comment: Can you explain the necessary logic required to obtain the expected result ?  Also In the expected result `TableA.Id` should be `ProductId` ?

Comment: Please also share your attempt. Are you looking for `linq` or `tsql` solution ?

Comment: both actually.but lets prioritize sql first.

Comment: You can get the required result using `LEFT JOIN`

Comment: I think `union` is warranted here, as there is nothing to prevent a ProductId from appearing in both tables B and C. Of course, `Table A's ProductId is foreign key to ProductId of TableB and Table C.` is structurally impossible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will want to use left join, as that returns null when there is no match on joining conditions. In the where clause for TableB and TableC you add the filtering for 'testcode'.  Use table aliases for TableA (TA), TableB (TB), and TableC (TC) if you care about abbreviating the code.

Assuming SQL Server:

```
CREATE TABLE #tableA (id int, Name varchar(100), ProductId varchar(100))
CREATE TABLE #tableB (id int, Name varchar(100), ProductId varchar(100), Code varchar(100))
CREATE TABLE #tableC (id int, OfferName varchar(100), ProductId varchar(100), Code varchar(100))

INSERT INTO #tableA VALUES (1, 'product1', 'prod1'), (2, 'product2', 'prod2')
INSERT INTO #tableB VALUES (1, 'RandomName', 'prod2', 'testcode')
INSERT INTO #tableC VALUES (1, 'HappyOffer', 'prod1', 'testcode')
--Your DDL values above

SELECT TA.ProductId AS [TableA.ProductId]
      ,TA.Name AS [TableA.Name]
      ,TB.Name AS [TableB.Name]
      ,TC.OfferName AS [TableC.OfferName]
  FROM #tableA TA
    LEFT JOIN #tableB AS TB ON TA.ProductId = TB.ProductId
    LEFT JOIN #tableC AS TC ON TA.ProductId = TC.ProductId
 WHERE (TB.Code = 'testcode' OR TC.Code = 'testcode')

--put the ordering here as a bonus, since you wanted prod2 listed first in the ProductId
ORDER BY CASE WHEN TA.ProductId = 'prod2' THEN 1 ELSE 2 END

/* --to drop the temp tables afterwards
DROP TABLE #tableA
DROP TABLE #tableB
DROP TABLE #tableC
*/
```

Produces output:

```
TableA.ProductId TableA.Name TableB.Name TableC.OfferName
---------------- ----------- ----------- ----------------
prod2            product2    RandomName  NULL
prod1            product1    NULL        HappyOffer
```

While this probably answers the question a foreign key only references a unique value in a column, like a primary key or a unique column.  The referenced value is optimally an integer, and primary keys tend to be integers since they are stored and joined more efficiently than strings.

Answer (score 0):

Inner join can help you I think.

```
SELECT column_name(s)
  FROM TableA
  INNER JOIN TableB
  ON TableA.ProductId = TableB.ProductId
  INNER JOIN TableC ON TableA.ProductId = 
  TableC.ProductId);
```